# Difference between typing a shell command, and save it to a file and using `cat myfile` to execute it?

Tags: shell, rsync, cat, backticks

I have an rsync command that works as expected when I type it directly into a terminal. The command includes several `--include='blah'` and `--exclude='foo'` type arguments. However, if I save that command to a one-line file called "myfile" and I try `cat myfile` (or, equivalently `$(cat myfile)`), the rsync command behaves differently.

I'm sure it is the exact same command in both cases.

Is this behavior expected/explainable?

Comment: Quoting/quote removal and word-splitting. Run `set -x` before you run both versions of the command to see the difference.

Comment: Whatever you are trying, `$(cat myfile)` is a wretched way to attempt to do it. The dot (aka `source` in Bash) evaluates the commands in a file in the context of the current shell, if that is what you want to accomplish. So just say `. myfile` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to this question. The point is that the `cat` command takes the contents of the file and treats it like a string. Any string operators (like the escape operator, ) are executed. Then, the final string output is what is passed to a command via the backticks.

As a solution, I've just made "myfile" a shell script that I can execute rather than trying to use `cat`.